# How to work with files using svelte when fs doesn't work?

Tags: file, svelte, fs

The [fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs) npm package doesn't seem to be supported anymore, and other packages I found like [write](https://www.npmjs.com/package/write), [write-to-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/write-to-file) and [read-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/read-file) rely on fs. So whenever I try to import any of them, I get an error: "ReferenceError: fs is not defined at main.js:5:2". What can I do right now to write something to a file, or read a file, using svelte?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Svelte usually runs in a context where there is no direct access to the file system (e.g. a browser). You then have to pass the data in some way or use the APIs available (like the [File System Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API)). The question lacks context of the architecture, e.g. whether this a client/server application or something using Electron or Tauri.

Answer (score 4):

The fs package from npm never worked, it's one of the Node.js [built-in packages](https://github.com/nodejs/node/tree/v18.0.0/lib). No need to install it.

When using SvelteKit, you're able to use fs in the [endpoints](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#endpoints) (when using a node compatible adapter) to access the filesystem on the server but not in the *.svelte files as these also need to run in the browser.